Can Python Wheels in an Addon for Blender 4.2 use the Default Python Packages Installed by Blender?
I am building an addon that will make use of some Python Wheels, but one of these wheels requires OpenImageIO and NumPy to work. I have researched and found that Blender has OpenImageIO and NumPy installed as Python modules. If I decide to exclude OpenImageIO and NumPy wheels from my addon, could the wheel that depends on them have problems running? In other words, would my addon detect and work fine with those modules that come by default in Blender?

Hello and welcome. I think it should work. But have you already tried it? Better try it first and see for yourself :)

This seems more about Python than blender.

@TheLabCatIt's about Blender and Python because Blender has a Python API that allows you to manipulate it.
